# Calculus2 integration by parts

Tags: calculus

$$\int e^{3x}(e^{4x}+7)~dx$$
(integration by parts)
I was solving this problem with
\begin{align*} 
u & =e^{3x} & dv & =e^{4x}+7\\
du & =3e^{3x}dx & v & = \frac{1}{4}e^{4x}+7x
\end{align*}
and I got
$$e^{3x}\left(\frac{1}{4}e^{4x}+7\right) - \int \left(\frac{1}{4}e^{4x}+7x\right)3e^{3x}~dx$$
This equation doesn't seem simpler than the previous equation.  What should I do next? or should I change $u$ to a different function?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Do you *have* to use integration by parts?

Comment: It isn't a _bad_ thing, though, to see that an alternative method will give the same result as a direct method... However, a reason you _won't_ like applying integration-by-parts for this integrand is that you now have the "harder" integrand $ \ x · e^{3x} \ $ to deal with.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:
$$
e^{3x}(e^{4x}+7)=e^{7x}+7e^{3x} \, .
$$
Don't use integration by parts if you can avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

There are simpler way to calculate this integral, but if you want to use the integration by parts, do it the other way around, that is
\begin{align}u &= e^{4x} + 7 & dv = e^{3x}dx \\
du &= 4e^{4x}dx & v= \frac13 e^{3x}\end{align}
Then you'll get
$$ \frac13 e^{3x}(e^{4x}+7) - \frac43 \int e^{3x}e^{4x} dx$$
which is simpler.

Integration by parts relies on dividing the integrated functions into two factors, one that has a simple derivative and the other that has a simple antiderivative. The trick is not not just about finding a way to split the function into two factors, but also about choosing which is which.

Comment: Regarding which term to set $u$ equal to, the [LIATE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts#LIATE_rule) rule is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the variable $u=e^x$, which implies that $dx=\frac{du}{u}$. Then your integral is very easy to calculate. Of course, this does not require any integration by parts, as some people in the comments already pointed out.